# Parse Server ignores ACL

Tags: parse-platform, acl, parse-server

I have a simple Parse Cloud Code function for my NewsFeed Objects. For these NewsFeed Objects I set an ACL such that the fromUser can write to it and the toUser can read and write to it. I try to get these objects for every user with the following function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("get_feed", async (request) => {
  let user = request.user;

  var query = new Parse.Query("NewsFeed");
  query.equalTo("toUser", user);
  query.include("fromUser");
  query.descending("createdAt");

  let result;
  try {
      result = await query.find();
  } catch (error) {
      throw error.message;
  }
  return result;
});
```

I would expect that I get all the objects which satisfy the query and have the following ACL:

```
"ACL" : {
    "xXl3OIndCP": {
        "read": true,
        "write": true
    },
    "VPuRMZGhcv": {
        "write": true
    }
}
```

But unfortunately it works only if I add public read access to the ACL such that it looks like this

```
"ACL" : {
    "*": {
        "read": true
    },
    "xXl3OIndCP": {
        "read": true,
        "write": true
    },
    "VPuRMZGhcv": {
        "write": true
    }
}
```

I don't think that this is the expected behavior or am I wrong? Did anybody face this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turned out that one has to pass the session token in the find() function so I had to use `result = await query.find({sessionToken : user.getSessionToken()});` instead of `result = await query.find();`